# Generating an Indoor Map from HERE Studio

Tags: mapping, gis, here-api

I have created an indoor map of a building using HERE Studio. The building consists of polygons for rooms, furniture, walls, etc., labels, and icons. There are 3 floors of data.

I would like to display this map in a web and mobile application, and I would need to be able to integrate a level switcher in both the web/mobile applications. Furthermore, I would need to be able to integrate an indoor routing network within this building (on all 3 floors).

On the web side of things, I see [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/venues-on-map), however this seems like it's only possible to generate indoor maps of facilities that have already been mapped out and are available as full JSON models (ie. you cannot integrate your own indoor floorplan data).

Is it possible to generate indoor maps of private venues on web/mobile, or are we limited to the repository of public venues that have indoor floorplans?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, have you checked the website in https://venues.here.com? HERE offers some services for Venue, customers and partners. Would you please refer which case you prefer?

Comment: Hi. I have a similar need. Can you please give some tutorial as to how to make indoor maps using HERE Studio. Is is free?